# How to sort a list of obfuscated digits within a string?

Tags: python, sorting

```
 list=[a1b,a100b,a2b,a99b]
```

I would like to transform by comparing the digit sandwitched the letter a and b like below.

```
 [a1b,a2b,a99b,a100b]
```

I tried

```
 list.sort()
```

But it didnt work well.

How can I sort?

Comment: `list.sort()` is doing its job by considering each element as a string. Only thing if we want the custom sorting based on the number which is sandwiched, we just need to pass it as key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**
*`natsort.natsorted`*
The [`natsort`](https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort) module works nicely here -

```
>>> from natsort import natsorted
>>> natsorted(['a1b','a100b','a2b','a99b'])
['a1b', 'a2b', 'a99b', 'a100b']
```

---

**Option 2**
*`sorted`* + *`re.search`*
With `regex`, I'd recommend defining a function that calls `re.search` to find and extract numbers, with a little checking to ensure that no exceptions are thrown when the pattern is not found in the string.

```
import re
def f(x):
     m = re.search('\d+', x)
     return int(m.group()) if m else x
```

```
>>> sorted(['a1b','a100b','a2b','a99b'], key=f)
['a1b', 'a2b', 'a99b', 'a100b']
```

You can achieve some speed gain if you have a preexisting list on which you call `list.sort`. `list.sort` performs an in-place sort and is going to be a bit faster than `sorted` because it operates in place and does not generate a copy of the data.

Another thing to note is that this version of a regex based sort is more robust than a `lambda`. It becomes possible to catch and handle exceptions, and you aren't constrained by the single line requirement of a `lambda`.

---

**Performance**

```
l = ['a1b','a100b','a2b','a99b'] * 10000
```

```
%timeit natsorted(l)
1 loop, best of 3: 437 ms per loop

%timeit sorted(l, key=f)
10 loops, best of 3: 92.4 ms per loop
```

Note that actual timings differ by versions, environment, and data. I have not benchmarked the other answers as they do not generalise well to arbitrarily structured input.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions to isolate the digits for the key function that you pass to `list.sort` or `sorted`:

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r'a(\d+)b')  # capture group of digits between a and b
lst = ['a1b', 'a100b', 'a2b', 'a99b']
sorted(lst, key=lambda s: int(pat.search(s).group(1)))
# ['a1b', 'a2b', 'a99b', 'a100b']
```

Comment: I'd suggest a little error handling for strings which do not match that pattern.

Comment: Well, there is no information in the post how these are supposed to be handled, hence the assumption is that there is aways such a group.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply extract middle value by `int(s[1:-1])` as a key to compare:

```
>>> L = ['a1b','a100b','a2b','a99b']
>>> L.sort(key=lambda s: int(s[1:-1]))
>>> L
['a1b', 'a2b', 'a99b', 'a100b']
```